# JavaScript date to Java LocalDateTime

Tags: javascript, java, http, datetime

On the server, the date field is of the LocalDateTime type. When I pass it to the frontend as Json, it is converted to the following format: `"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"`.

This is what this field looks like in DTO:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime term;
```

This is how the date received from the server looks on the frontend:

```
02-06-2020 04:15:05
```

On the frontend I try to get the current date and convert it according to the DTO format:

```
term: moment().format("DD-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

If you output this date in the console, it will look like this:

```
{"term":"02-06-2020 12:00:00"}
```

But when I send a request to the server, an error occurs: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`. I realized that this is due to the date format of the DTO, because if the DTO field has the string `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")`, then the error will not occur and the request will pass successfully. But why doesn't it work, because I'm putting the date in the correct form? It looks exactly the same as the response from the server, but still doesn't work? Or is there a better way to send datetime from the frontend to the server?

This is the request I send from the frontend:

```
 const сard = {
      name: "name",
      description: "description",
      term: moment().format("DD-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
 };

 fetch({
    url: `${API_BASE_URL}/cards`,
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(card)
 });
```

Comment: What is the request you send to the server? You should put the front-end code in the OP

Comment: @laruiss I added the request to the question

Comment: Re "a better way": often a time value is sent like `moment().unix()` as it's less ambiguous and easier to parse. Does the server expect local or UTC? According to the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), the year token should be YYYY, lower case yyyy is for era (which is likely irrelevant here).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the date formats. In order for everything to work, the following `JsonFormat` must be installed on the server for the `LocalDateTime` field:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
```

I don't quite understand why, but it only works that way. If you write `YYYY` instead of `yyyy` or write `hh` instead of `HH`, queries from the frontend will return an error. This is a bit of a strange solution, but it works.

On the frontend, I transform the date using moment.js to the following format:

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
```

After that the requests are successfully executed